# Socat not cleaning up cleanly after itself via ssh

Tags: ssh, socat

I am trying to talk to a machine that is connected to my local machine, using ssh, socat, and another utility I made.

On source machine I am doing:

`ssh root@localhost -p 2004 'socat -u TCP-LISTEN:5000 OPEN:foo.test,creat'`

(The 4000 maps to the 5000 using my utility that is currently running, not relevant to problem)
then doing:

`socat -d -d TCP:localhost:4000 ./some_file`

And the file transfer occurs correctly, the problem is that I need to be doing these kinds of operations in quick succession and the initial `socat TCP-LISTEN` server setup does not exit cleanly I guess because I need to wait until the port cleans up, otherwise I get errors of:

`2016/05/14 11:56:01 socat[655] E bind(3, {LEN=0 AF=2 0.0.0.0:5000}, 16): Address already in use`

Is there a socat option I'm missing that cleans up cleanly on any kind of exit? I basically need this for a file transfer, I only need the socat on the remote machine to go off once.

EDIT: I'm purposefully having to use `ssh` because the file path for `OPEN` is different each time and this will have to be done quickly, one after another.

Answer (score 4):

You can change the `TCP-LISTEN:5000` to `TCP-LISTEN:5000,reuseaddr` but the problem may simply be that, for example, during testing you are interrupting the `ssh` with <kbd>Control-C</kbd> and this is not stopping the socat on the remote.

Note that you can avoid having to repeatedly launch `socat` to do the same thing over again by simply asking it to `fork` and listen for a new connection again:

```
socat -u TCP-LISTEN:5000,reuseaddr,fork OPEN:foo.test,creat
```

Comment: I should have been clear, it needs to be a one time creation because the file path is different each time